# UserControl C# KeyPress

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an usercontrol. This usercontrol have 1 textBox and 1 button.

My usercontrol

```
    private void textBoxCombo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            buttonCombo_Click(null, null);
    }

    private void buttonCombo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Execute some tasks!!
    }
```

I have 2 forms: father form and inherited form.

father form code: Keypreview is seted as true

```
            protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
            e.Handled = true;   // stop annoying beep

        // call base handler...
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    private void formBase_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
    }
```

inherited Form - In my form have 3 components : 1 TextBox, 1 MyUserControl and 1 ComboBox.

When my inherited form start, the cursor is focus in the textbox. If I press ENTER, the focus change to MyUserControl. If I press ENTER again, the focus change to ComboBox.

But this combobox will be filled with data process in my user control.

The problem is here ...

when the cursor is in textBox from my user control. If I press ENTER, my user control will execute the click button and the form will change the focus to next component .. the combo. But the combo receive the focus before finish the button click process, then the combo havent data now.

How to control this?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what the problem is. You may want to go into detail as to what is not working as expected. In addition, without some code to go by, speculation and more questions are about all you may get. I suggest as a minimum posting the user control code and posting how the combo box relates to the user control. I suggest you peruse the SO [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section. In this case the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful.

Comment: "But the combo receive the focus before finish **the button click process**", which button click are you talking about here, the enter key button?

Comment: the button from my user control. The same button that executed when I type enter in my user control.

Comment: Do a test and see if it works without this line `e.Handled = true;`. If it still doesn't work without that line, I think `formBase_KeyDown` is not the correct place, I think you want `KeyUp` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set `KeyPress` Event on the parent form,
DO NOT forget to set `KeyPreview` property to `TRUE`.
The event will call a public method in the user control that will perform the click on the button.

For Example:

**Form1:**

DO NOT forget to set `KeyPreview` property to TRUE.

```
 // User control will be decleared globaly
 private UserControl1 MyUserControl;
 // Called from the load event for example
 private void  UserControlDefinitions()
 {
     MyUserControl = new UserControl1();
     MyUserControl.Location = new Point(5, 5);
     this.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
 }


 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
     {
         if (MyUserControl != null)
         {
             MyUserControl.EnterWasClickedFromOutside();
         }
     }
 }
```

**UserControl:**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void EnterWasClickedFromOutside()
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Was Pressed In Form1");
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the description of my question ... can you verify now?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your Form not move forward when the active control is of your usercontrol type:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if(!(ActiveControl is UserControl1))
        {
            SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
        }                
    }                
}
```

Then in your UserControl, you can ask the Form to move forward after your button is done doing its thing:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }            
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Button1 in UserControl");
    Form frm = this.ParentForm;
    frm.SelectNextControl(frm.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```